# How does RequireJS use multiversion jQuery and install jQuery plugin to the right version of jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs

I am developing an app with jQuery 1.7.2, recently I need to upgrade a jQuery plugin, but that's dependent on >= jQuery 1.9.

So I have to use multiversion jQuery in one page (this maybe not a good practice).

How could I install this plugin attaching to jQuery 1.9 and jQuery 1.9 wrapped in a module doesn't expose to the global.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used `$.noConflict` to remove the one jquery in global, and wrap the plugin in AMD module `define` function. Although it's not a best practice but it solved my problem.